# Review Audit Dupe Search

Tags: bug, review-audits

I was doing first post reviews, and saw a question that I assumed must have been answered before, so I went through the flag process of looking for dupes. However instead of showing me search results where I could assess whether it was a dupe, I was informed I had **failed** a review audit. Had I been unable to find a dupe I would have actually voted the question up for being high quality, but because I searched first, that search triggered an audit failure.

It seems the search results need to be shown before revealing the question to be an audit. Otherwise doing thorough research is deemed a failure.

Comment: What does "went through the flag process of looking for dupes" mean? You clicked `flag`?

Comment: @KateGregory yes I clicked flag. I don't remember precisely where it caught me, but I was on my way to looking for dupes in the flag process

Comment: Reading the linked question, I may be misunderstanding something. I thought the results when you say it might be a dupe are search results. If they are actually flags from other people, then that's not what I was looking for. I was just trying to search, not peek.

Comment: @KateGregory, what is the *preferred* way to search for potential dupes when reviewing first posts?

Comment: @AlienArrays, I don't have the reputation to open/close, but I'll take your suggestion as meaning don't hit the flag button until I've searched elsewhere. That said, doesn't the system try to look for duplicates when you are drafting a question? (Didn't find it in the case of my question here though!)

Comment: I freely admit, this really *sucks* for duplicates. Just know that you were doing the right thing and don't worry about it any further.